# can't make div items to take the full length of it

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

im trying to postion items to be in the center of the div but it doesn't work

this is a picture for desired output 
[image]

i don't know why the div items are going to left and the input text don't take the full length of the div
im also trying to add space between the text and the gear icon of the orange buttons

and this is my code :

```
<af:dialog contentWidth="400" type="none" id="aaa" modal="true">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 sm-b-b">
            <div class="sm-padding-5">
                <af:inputText inlineStyle="display: inline-block;width:100%" value="sohoooooooooooooooooo"
                              simple="true" id="it1"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 sm-b-b">
            <div class="sm-padding-5">
                <af:button inlineStyle="display: inline-block;width:100%" text="Search" id="b1"></af:button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <af:forEach var="node" items="#{bindings.ViewObj11.collectionModel}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 sm-b-b">
                <div class="sm-padding-5">
                    <af:link text="#{bindings.Value1.inputValue}" styleClass="btn btn-primary white" id="ot1">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-gear"></span>
                    </af:link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </af:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Style in your style sheet

```
 .sm-b-b{
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
 }
```